# Nontrivial homomorphisms from G to T

Tags: complex-analysis, group-theory, metric-spaces, abelian-groups, continuous-homomorphisms

> Let $G$ be a compact metric abelian group. $T$ be the circle group.
>   Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the set of all finite linear combinations of continuous
>   homomorphisms from $G \to T$. I want to show that the its uniform
>   closure contains all complex continuous functions.

It is easy to see that $\mathcal{A}$ is a self adjoint algebra. Also the identity homomorphism is non zero for all elements of $G$. The only thing that remains to show is that $\mathcal{A}$ separates points.
Let $a,b \in G$, $a\neq b$. I want to find an element $\phi$ in $\mathcal{A}$ for which $\phi(a)\neq \phi(b)$. I firmly believe that we can find a continuous homomorphism $\phi$. Then it is enough to show $\phi(ab^{-1}) \neq 1$. So it boils down to show that

$x\neq e$ implies there exist a continuous homomorphism $\phi$ such that $\phi(x)\neq 1$

I am stuck here. I dont know if it is true or not. Counterexamples are welcomed.

Comment: Yes, it is true. The set of the linear combinations of continuous homomorphisms is  dense in $C(G) $ by Stone-Weierstrass because the set separates points of $G$ as follows from the discussion here  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/210180/existence-of-non-trivial-characters-on-compact-abelian-group